# How to add Layout on top of background image in Android

Tags: android

I want to add Linear Layout on top of my background image as shown in below image(that horizontal bars). [image]

But that is not working.I have checked by adding background color but it didn't shown in the preview.
Below is the way that I had added the Linear Layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/back">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logo_big"
        android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The ss u added is the required result u want ? Also, did u debugged the app on your device and checkes instead of the preview only?

Comment: Yes. But I'm getting oly the background image and top logo. Not the rest. So I just want to know how to add the rest.

Comment: Why don't you try RelativeLayout for better alignment of viewgroups or better use ConstraintLayout.

Comment: Is this your complete xml code? Coz there seems no data in the linearlayouts that u added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a `<RelativeLayout>` around your `<LinearLayout>`.
Like this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/back">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_big"
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:

Set orientation = vertical in your parent LinearLayout.

Solution 2:

Use RelativeLayout for better UI experience.